# What is the best way to show paragraphs & headings with Objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I've been looking online and surprised that I haven't found an answer. I have about 20/30 lines of text to show, with about 5 headings and one section at the end with phone numbers/emails (which need to be marked up for clicking). What is the best way to show this stuff?

Do I use core text? (There's no easy to follow examples for this online)

How do I markup a heading in the text?

Should I use web view or stick with native?

Comment: Webviews are great for styled text. Quick and easy. Unless you run into rendering speed issues, I would always go for that option.

Comment: Is that really a good thing to do ? It seems weird to me, rendering text in a native environment with an HTML plugin. Does the text still look like native text?